# angular.copy() object has more data than original?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

This is driving me crazy.

I have this setup where I have a controller which is linked to a block which gets ng-repeated in the template.

this is in that controller:

```
ctrl.original = angular.copy($scope.program);
```

the $scope.program is getting created by the ng-repeat directive.

Now there is a sub-array in the json I'm looping over called `program_authorizations`

When I go to render that array in a template the another ng-repeat, it shows that it's an empty array. Viewing the response as raw json in the browser show's it's not. console.log() calls in the promise's .then() callback show it as empty.

BUT when I do a reset, doing:

```
ctrl.original = angular.copy($scope.program);
```

the array is populated!! Super super weird. I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be a timing problem, i.e. the array gets populated after being copied. But I cannot tell just by this code. If you could reproduce this in a fiddle, you would probably receive much more help. For the time being you can test my assumption by adding some `console.log`s before populating the array from the service and before copying. Also, if the JSON call is not through Angular (jQuery maybe?) make sure you call `$apply()` at the proper place.

Comment: Gah! @#$@% So it's because I'm also binding that array value to the ng-model of a select menu with the multiple option. I guess what's happening is that the array gets loaded (I can see the rest of the data from the JSON so I know it's getting there), and then gets over written by the select menu somehow. I think because the values in the array are only IDs which refer to users, and the options get populated by values that don't match the existing array. I guess that dumps the existing values. Thanks for the help though!!